# PKIX path building failed downloading from maven.oracle.com

Tags: jenkins

I have installed the certificate from the maven.oracle.com website (*.oracle.com) into the following stores:

```
/etc/ssl/cacerts/trustStore (defined in Global MAVEN_OPTS with correct passwd)
/home/jenkins/cacerts
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
/etc/pki/java/cacerts
/etc/ssl/cacerts
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_192-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/usr/java/jdk-11.0.1/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/oracle/12.2/client64/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Jenkins has JDK8 and JDK11 installed, this build is configured to use JDK8.

Using keytool on the stores shows the *.oracle.com certificate to be installed with an alias of maven.oracle.com.

The command to obtain the certificate was:

```
keytool -printcert -rfc -sslserver maven.oracle.com
```

This was then copy and pasted in vi to create a cert file.

The command to install the certificate was in the format;

```
keytool -import -file maven.oracle.com.cer -alias maven.oracle.com -keystore /opt/oracle/12.2/client64/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

The Jenkins build job I am trying to run still fails with a certificate error:

```
[INFO] Downloading from maven.oracle.com: https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading from maven.oracle.com: https://maven.oracle.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ucp/12.2.0.1/ucp-12.2.0.1.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping XXXXX
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.866 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-03T16:45:49+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/495M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXXXX:jar:13.2.3.370: Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:pom:12.2.0.1 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I do not understand why the certificate is not being picked up from any of the stores.  I have previously done this for another certificate and that worked as expected.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an actual certificate to download the JDBC driver. The easiest way is to download these from [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html) and manually install it.

However, you need to have login credentials to oracle.com and then encrypt that password. Please review the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for more details.